# Phpmyadmin accepting only one entry from json array having multiple input values

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, api, foreach

Can anyone please help me for setting the correct foreach loop for sending multiple input values to the database (MySQL), Whenever I execute this code in postman only one entry gets uploaded in the database. I want to send multiple "user_id" at once.

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input', true));

foreach($input->users as $user) {
    $groupId = $user->group_id;

    $groups = Group::where("group_id", $groupId)
        ->get()->first();

    foreach($input->users as $user2) {

        $groupMembers = new GroupMembers();

        $userId = $user2->user_id;
        $groupMembers->group_id = $groups->group_id;

        $users1 = Users::where("user_id", $userId)
            ->get()->first();

        $groupMembers->member_user_id = $users1->user_id;
        $response = json_decode($groupMembers, true);

        $save = $groupMembers->save();
```

Input json:

```
{
    "users" : [{
        "group_id" : "1",
        "user_id" : ["2", "3", "4"]
}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
foreach($input->users as $user) {
          $groupId = $user->group_id;

          $groups = Group::where("group_id", $groupId)
              ->get()->first();

          foreach($user->user_id as $userId) {

              $groupMembers = new GroupMembers();

              $groupMembers->group_id = $groups->group_id;

              $users1 = Users::where("user_id", $userId)
                  ->get()->first();

              $groupMembers->member_user_id = $userId;
              $response = json_decode($groupMembers, true);

              $save = $groupMembers->save();}
        }
```

Comment: Postman is throwing an exception: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object
Please check my input json as well and suggest an edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you are iterating through `users` it should be `user_id`

```
foreach($input->users['user_id'] as $user) {
```

Comment: Postman is throwing an exception: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined property: stdClass::$user_id